# Error in linsolve

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

```
A=imread('lena_color.jpg');
x1=2.1;
b=A*x1;
b=double(b);
x1=double(x1);
opts.UT = true; opts.TRANSA = false;
A1 = linsolve(x1,b,opts);
figure;
imshow(A1);
```

This gives:

```
 error >>??? Error using ==> linsolve
First and second arguments must be single or double.

Error in ==> test at 9
A1= linsolve(b,x1,opts);
```

Please help to resolve this.

Also is there any other method to solve an Equation of the form say `Eq1= A*2.1 + B*3.5 +C*1.5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with the dimensions, not with the arguments.
The following code works for me:

```
% you can switch it with your own image after you see it works
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
A = im2double(I);

% scalar*matrix works in matlab commandline,
% but needs to be defined when it comes to equations
x1=2.1*eye(size(A));
b=A*x1;

opts.UT = true; 
opts.TRANSA = false;
A1 = linsolve(x1,b,opts);

figure; imshow(A1);
```

[edit] to @SKM and @gary, here's a detailed solution (for the RGB case):

```
% example for RGB image
Img= im2double( imread('peppers.png') );
Dim = size(Img, 3);

% transform the original image, 
% by multiplying every color channel by different scalar.
% that is going to be a very red image...
a = [1 0.5 0.2]; 
aMat = []; newImg = [];
for Ind=1:Dim
    aMat(:, :, Ind) = a(Ind)*eye( size(Img, 1), size(Img, 2) );
    newImg(:, :, Ind) = a(Ind)*squeeze(Img(:, :, Ind));
end

% recontructing original image
recontrcutedImg=[];
for Ind=1:Dim
    recontrcutedImg(:, :, Ind) = linsolve( aMat(:, :, Ind), newImg(:, :, Ind) );
end

% show the images
figure;
subplot(1, 3, 1); imagesc(Img); title('original');
subplot(1, 3, 2); imagesc(newImg); title('changed image');
subplot(1, 3, 3); imagesc(recontrcutedImg); title('reconstructed image');
```

Comment: @gary: The code works fine for gray scale. However, it gives error for RGB >>??? Error using ==> eye
Unknown command option.

Error in ==> test at 5
x1=2.1*eye(size(A));  Also, if the coeeficient(x's) is also a 2D matrix then the result is not same ie the operation while solving the linear equation is not a reversible operation. How to resolve this?Thank you for your time & patience.

Comment: solving in matlab in multi dimensional can be tricky, as `answer = A\b` won't work if A isn't 2D. maybe you can try somehing like `I = rand(10, 20, 3); newI = 3*I; for Ind=1:3; esta = linsolve(newI(:, :, Ind), I(:, :, Ind)); estI(:, :, Ind) = esta; end; figure;imshow(estI);`

Comment: Could you kindly clarify where is the linear equation which is to be solved and what is the meaning of esta = linsolve(newI(:, :, Ind), I(:, :, Ind));

Comment: Is it possible to multiply two images of different dimensions? For instance size(A)=512 256 3 and size(B)= 256 512 3 to give RGB image of 256 256 3? I tried it,but the error is ??? Error using ==> mtimes
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in ==> multiply at 17
    aMat(:, :, Ind) = a(Ind)*eye( size(Img, 1), size(Img, 2) );

Comment: it just needed `im2double`. I was feeding it the output of `imread`.